# dynamic to concrete type with automapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, dto

I do a post with an anonymous type on an WebApi controller in the body I have this `new { Firstname = "AA", Lastname = "BB"}`

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]dynamic person)
{
}
```

When I hit the controller, `person` is not null and I can see the the properties with their data.

In the controller I'd like convert the `dynamic` type to my concrete type `Person`

```
public class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

I tried with `Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<dynamic, Person>());`

When I do this

```
var person = Mapper.Map<dynamic, Person>(source);
```

All the properties of `person` are `null`.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html), instead of...

```
    var person = Mapper.Map<dynamic, Person>(source);
```

...just use...

```
    var person = Mapper.Map<Person>(source);
```

Full example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
}

//Main
Mapper.Initialize( cfg => {} );
dynamic source = new ExpandoObject();
source.FirstName = "Hello";
source.LastName = "World";
var person = Mapper.Map<Person>(source);

Console.WriteLine("GetType()= '{0}' ToString()= '{1}'", person.GetType().Name, person);
```

Output:

```
GetType()= 'Person' ToString()= 'Hello World'
```

[Link to DotNetFiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Bsm9w)